# Event listener "remembers" preveously fetched data?

Tags: javascript, events, fetch, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to display json data with infinite scroll solution. The code works fine up until that point where I recall the fetch function with a different api url: the script displays the first 20 items as intended, but as soon as the scroll event fires it starts to list the preveously fetched data. What goes wrong? Thanks

```
//Fetch api data

    function loadData(id) {
      fetch(apiURL+'/'+id)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
          getData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    
    // Sort and loop
    function getData(data) {
      
      selectContainer.innerHTML = "";
      const allDataCount = data.length;
      let items = 20;
      let counter = 0;
    
        // Sort array by numbers
      data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.IndexInData - b.IndexInData;
      });
      
      //Infinite load - add event listener
      window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollEvent);
    
      render(data);
    
      //Loop through data
      function render(data) {
        for (counter; counter < items && counter < allDataCount; counter++) {
          renderTemplate(data[counter]);
        }
      }
    
      
      //Event function
      function onScrollEvent() {
        const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;
        if (
          scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5
        ) {
          items += 20;
          render(data);
        }
      }
    }
    
    function renderTemplate(templateData) {...}
```

Comment: where you call ```loadData``` function. normally, we call api in ```useEffect```, so you need to removeEventlistener when component unmount. set function like this in the end of ``useEffect``` :```return () => window.removeEventListener([eventname here])```

Comment: @danhuong I'm using plain JavaScript

Comment: @tm1992 you need to recalculate the `counter`, increase the counter value each time when your scroll event is trigger

Comment: @ToujouAya the `counter` is incrementing inside the loop